# Qt just loads the translations of UI strings but not strings in the code

Tags: qt, translation

I have a lot of form and strings in my project that the translatable strings are boxed in the tr() function. I translated all of strings by Linguist, but when I load the correspond qm file, just the strings that are in the UI being translated.

For example, if I had a form containing a label with "Hello World!" text, it is translated to "Olleh Dlrow!"(just for say). 
But in the code if I wrote:

```
if ( condition )
    ui.setTitle(tr("MainWindow"));
else
    ui.setTitle(tr("SecondaryWindow"));
```

no translation of **MainWindow** or **SecondaryWindow** is done and the original text is shown.

Any idea? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you load the .qm file before or after you set the titles?

Comment: And do you have translations for "MainWindow" and "SecondaryWindow" in your translation file?

Comment: Of course, I have translated the "MainWindow" and "SecondaryWindow" in my .ts file and laod .qm file then retranslateUi() after installing the .qm files.

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain the solution for somebody in the situation like me.
Consider I have a class named MyForm. I defined a namspace for my project called MyNmeSpace.

```
/*    MyForm.cpp    */

using namespace MyNmeSpace;

MyForm::MyForm(QWidget* parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{}
```

**1)** If the user wraps the strings in the **tr()** function, they won't be translated. For enabling translation, he must use the **QApplication::translate("ClassName", "str", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)** like:

```
/*    MyForm.cpp approach 1   */

using namespace MyNmeSpace;

MyForm::MyForm(QWidget* parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{
    bool condition; /* sth you like */

    if ( condition )
        // ui.setWindowTitle(tr("MainWindow"));  <= won't work
        ui.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MyForm", "MainWindow", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    else
        // ui.setWindowTitle(tr("SecondaryWindow"));  <= won't work
        ui.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MyForm", "SecondaryWindow", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
}
```

In this approach the translations in the .ts file are written **MyForm** in each entry.

**2)** Remove the **using namespace MyNmeSpace;** from the beggining of the *MyForm.cpp* and specify the scope like:

```
/*    MyForm.cpp approach 2   */

MyNmeSpace::MyForm::MyForm(QWidget* parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{
    bool condition; /* sth you like */

    if ( condition )
        ui.setWindowTitle(tr("MainWindow"));  // Now works
    else
        ui.setWindowTitle(tr("SecondaryWindow"));  // Now works
}
```

In this approach the translations in the .ts file are written like **MyNmeSpace::MyForm** in each entry.